# Can't create mesh? Mesh is invisible or somewhere hidden?

Tags: mesh

I cant create a mesh anymore :( or anything else. if I use Shift A and create something, the mesh, light or whatever doesnt appear on my view port. As location I get: -nan(ind)m and when I try to set it back to zero nothing happens. I really don't want to restart my model :/

It happened after I saved my project.
I could recreate the entire model in a new project but I fear to lose again endless hours of work.

[image]

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful but from what it seems *"location I get: -nan(ind)m"* you're out of luck with that object. This is rather rare error with numbers of object location, for some reason it thinks transform is defined with something which is not a number (nan). If there aren't any save points try to import object into another blend file or copy paste it. Also which Blender version, how did you create object, how many objects in the scene.. to get some context for this.

Comment: i added a screenshot. I had basically only 2 objects in scene, the one you see on the image and another bit more complex. I created the object as already mentioned via shift + A with blender 2.8 ... but to fair its in Beta so error like this were expected. I already exported the more complex object and started a new file...

Comment: 2.8 indeed is beta though errors like this generally shouldn't happen. Starting new file is probably the most viable option in this case

Comment: If you use `File->Load Factory Settings` can you add a new object? If not, try a newer build (2.80 beta builds are updated daily) and if it still happens then report it as a bug - `Help->Report a Bug`